# make more modular graphQL project

Tags: javascript, graphql

I would like to start by writing an environment which unfortunately I had to use

```
windows 10 / 64 bit's
Visual-Studio-Code
```

I'm new in GraphQL technology that why I have this kind of questions.

I do not understand why when all the resolvers functions are in one file, the whole project works great.

unfortunately when it starts to take more care of the structure, everything starts to making new error

As below I have this type of error, when I try to blast off node server

```
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��c
                                                                  ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Weronika\Documents\michal\first-graphgl-server\src\index.js:5:18)
```

Here I am posting the project structure

```
--database/
--src/
----generated/
----resolvers/
------Mutation.js
------AuthPayload.js
----index.js
--package.json
--.graphqlconfig.yml
schema.graphql
utils.js
```

Moreover, I post my dependencies below:

```
{
  "name": "first-graphql-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.12",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "prisma-binding": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

And, below, Mutation.js file, which is the problem

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { APP_SECRET, getUserId } = require('../utils')


async function signup(parent, args, context, info) {

  const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)

  const user = await context.db.mutation.createUser({
    data: {...args, password},
  }, `{ id }`)

  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET)

  return {
    token,
    user,
  }
}

async function login(parent, args, context, info) {

  const user = await context.db.query.user({ where: { email: args.email } }, `{ id password }`)
  
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('No such user found')
  }

  const valid = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, user.password)

  if (!valid) throw new Error('Invalid password')

  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET)

  return {
    token,
    user,
  }
}

function post(parent, args, context, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(context)
  return context.db.mutation.createLink(
    {
      data: {
        url: args.url,
        description: args.description,
        postedBy: { connect: { id: userId } },
      },
    },
    info,
  )
}

module.exports = {
  signup,
  login,
  post,
}
```

And the last file which I have to copy to the post, but the most important one, index.js file

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding');


const Mutation = require('./resolvers/Mutation')
const AuthPayload = require('./resolvers/AuthPayload')

function feed(parent, args, context, info) {
  return context.db.query.links({}, info)
}

const Query = {
  feed,
}

const resolvers = { 
  Query,
  Mutation,
  AuthPayload
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db: new Prisma({
      typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
      endpoint: 'https://eu1.prisma.sh/mjaracz-b561d8/example/dev',
      secret: 'mysecret123',
      debug: true,
    }),
  }),
})
server.start(() => console.log(`Server is running on the https://localhost:4000`))
```

Please let me know if any of you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that, you have wrong encoding in Mutation.js file or some wird white spaces.

Comment: but unfortunately I do not give answers to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with the implementation itself.
There is an invalid character in one of your files:

`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��c`

Notice the `��` characters.

Remove them to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Do you think it can be because I'm using async -  await?  
Asks a question because I still can not figure out what I can use the forbidden character.. 

unfortunately, before I put the question on the stack, I had exactly the same error with the querys file, which the resolver has now moved to index.js

have a good day and Take care :)